# SwiftUI as a drawing board for printer label designer

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I use SwiftUI as a drawing board for a printer label designer? I want to combine views (or add multiple views to a parent view) for different images, text and barcode etc. (after the user select what they want to design and print).

Currently I have put different views (separate view for image, text, barcode etc) inside an instance of TabView and use the tabItem() modifier for each view. I tried using different stacks (ZStack, HStack) but it does not work, is there any other methods I can try?

Here is part of the code for the label designer with only text:

```
var body: some View
    {
            ZStack(alignment: .center)
            {
                ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) //Label Design Area
                {
                    Rectangle()
                        .opacity(0.3)
                        .offset(x:0,y:0)
                        .frame(width: (LabelWidth * mmTOpt), height: (LabelHeight * mmTOpt))                    
                    ZStack()
                    {
                        TextField("", text: $Text1)
                            .offset(x:offsetx + location.x , y:offsety + location.y)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .submitLabel(.done) // changed to IOS 15
                            .font(Font.custom(fontused, size: fontsize))
                            .disabled(tfdisabled)
                            .gesture(simpleDrag.simultaneously(with: fingerDrag))
                            .underline(textunderlined)
                            .bold(textbold)
                            .italic(textitalic)
                            .strikethrough(textstrikethrough)
```

I tried to combine the image view using HStack with the following code:

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, matching: .images, photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                            Text("Select a photo")
                        }
…….
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This type of global question is really not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Pare it down to a basic question, and add the specific code. If you can't put together code, show your research to show what you have tried. Good luck!